# Copy data in Vector<float> to Vector<Mat> (Opencv/C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

In C++ I have the following code. I'm trying to copy the data stored in a vector into a matrix (inside a vector). I've tried to do this:

```
Vector<float> vec;
// Let's imagine that vec contains 10 float values: {1,2,3 ...., 10}
// I'd like to copy those numbers into a Mat variable 
Vector<Mat> myMats;
myMats.push_back(Mat(2,5,CV_32FC1,&vec.front()));
```

It works. However!, when modifying the content on the vector "vec" and trying to insert it in another position in my vector of Mat, all of them get the value of the last "push_back" operation. All entries in "myMats" are overwritten with the last entry. How can I solve this?

I think the problem is using the reference ("&") that modifies each time the address, where to look.

Comment: Why do you push a address of temporary object?

Comment: yes, just edited my question mentioning that. I made it work at the first time like this, then I had to modify the code but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Also, it is unclear for me what are you want to do. Please describe what is happening now and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I've figured out how to do it (creating a temporary Mat)

```
Mat temp_;
temp_ = Mat(2,5,CV_32FC1,&vec.front());
myMats.push_back(temp_.clone());
```

I guess there is a more efficient way but this works ok.

Comment: please accept your own answer if possible. The reason why you have to clone is that this Mat constructor just uses the data pointer instead of allocating own memory.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has already solved it by himself. However, this is some clarification if someone come to this question later.

`cv::Mat` is a container with a pointer to the actual data. When you create a `cv::Mat` like this:

```
cv::Mat some_mat;
```

The `cv::Mat` is created in the stack and it will point to the data in the heap by keeping a pointer in its struct.  When you copy a `cv::Mat` using its copy constructor/Assignment  like this:

```
cv::Mat another_mat=some_mat;
```

or this:

```
some_vector_of_mats.push_back(some_mat);
```

a shallow copy will happen. In other words, the header of the `cv::Mat` (rows and columns count, type...) will be deeply copied and The pointer that points to the actual data will be shallow copied. But the actual data will not be copied. So what happened in the OP case that each time a cv::Mat is pushed to the vector a shallow copy is happend. The pointer copied with no change in its value. So, all the cv::Mat's are pointing to the same place. Thus leads to any change in one of them data will affect the others.